# Staking / Unstaking EOS

Tags: scatter

I am getting a "Failed to fetch" transaction failure when I try to both stake/delegate and unstake/undelegate my EOS on eostoolkit. Account is correctly attached via Scatter. Any pointers?

Comment: Try bloks.io! Welcome to EOS!!

Answer (score 1):

are you aware of the new powerup model that has been deployed to main net?
https://eos.io/news/eos-powerup-model-explained/

eospowerup.io
Free daily powerups
Automated powerup service based on utilization
1% fee

arm.chintai.io
Automated powerups based on utilization
100% fee if paid with EOS
0% fee if paid with CHEX

github.com/eosauthority/authority_charge_client
Pay as you Go model - Pay per transaction
There are no powerups required
Fees range from 0.0005 to 0.0010 based on network